# Is it possible to get channel ID by name in DPP?

Tags: c++, discord

The title says it all... I want to delete the channel, but I need id.

```
dpp::channel example
```

has attribute named id, but it is not id that i need.

`Thank you in advance

```
dpp::channel example;

example.id - id has no.. id, idk.
```